# How to change the progress bar text color based on the progress percentage in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, progress-bar, textblock

I've written the below code to show a progress bar and a text showing the percentage. THis text block will be placed on the bar itself. But the font is white now. How can I add a condition to make it black if the installation progress hasn't passed  it and if it had then I need to change it to white. How can I do this? Please advice.

```
<ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Background="#FF1B1A1A" Value="{Binding Progress }" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="20,182,20,121" Height="20" BorderBrush="#FF1B1A1A"  >
        <ProgressBar.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF0A92FB"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF022F52" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </ProgressBar.Foreground>

    </ProgressBar>
    <TextBlock Name="progressLbl" Text="{Binding Progress,StringFormat={}{0}%}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="18,182,10,121" Width="40" Height="20" Foreground="#FFE6E6E6" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>
```

Comment: DataTrigger on your TextBlock hooked to a LessThan/GreaterThan converter bound to the Value of ProgressBar should make quick work of it.

Answer (score 0):

Binding `TextBlock's Text` property as below, and use `DataTrigger` with `Converter` for `Foreground`.

```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=PBar1}" Margin="92,216,159,54">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=PBar1, Converter={StaticResource ConvPercentageKey}}" Value="LessThan50">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, ElementName=PBar1,  Converter={StaticResource ConvPercentageKey}}" Value="MoreThan50">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
```

Converter code :

```
public class PercentageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double v = Double.Parse(value.ToString());
        if (v < 50)
            return "LessThan50";
        else
            return "MoreThan50";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```